# Cannot locate and click an element using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I really tried almost everything that comes on my mind to click on buttons No

Bellow is an entire HTML code of it

```
<div class="row nest">
   <div class="condition-row clearfix" id="condition_row_1">
      <div class="field small-12 medium-6 columns">
         <label>
         Does this item still have the retail tags attached? <span>*</span>
         </label>
         <div class="btn-group elastic">
            <a class="pill condition-tags btn white sml ">Yes</a><a class="pill condition-tags btn white sml ">No</a>        
         </div>
         <p class="error clearfix" id="condition-tags_error" style="display: none;">Please select an answer</p>
         <input class="required" type="hidden" id="property[condition-tags]" name="property[condition-tags]" value="">
      </div>
      <div class="field small-12 medium-6 empty columns"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="condition-row clearfix" id="condition_row_2">
      <div class="field small-12 medium-6 columns">
         <label>
         Does this item have any signs of wear? <span>*</span>
         </label>
         <div class="btn-group elastic">
            <a class="pill condition-wear btn white sml ">Yes</a><a class="pill condition-wear btn white sml ">No</a>        
         </div>
         <p class="error clearfix" id="condition-wear_error" style="display: none;">Please select an answer</p>
         <input class="required" type="hidden" id="property[condition-wear]" name="property[condition-wear]" value="">
      </div>
      <div class="field small-12 medium-6 empty columns"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="condition-row clearfix" id="condition_row_3">
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <div class="field small-12 columns" id="condition-custom-outer" style="display: none;">
         <hr class="hr-line">
         <label>Tag any signs of wear.</label>
         <div class="btn-group elastic">
            <a class="pill condition-list btn white sml ">Scuffs or scratches</a><a class="pill condition-list btn white sml ">Damaged or missing stones</a><a class="pill condition-list btn white sml ">Tarnishing</a>            <a class="condition-add-custom btn white sml" id="condition-add-custom" href="javascript:void(0);">
            <span class="icon-plus-solid"></span>Add your own
            </a>
         </div>
         <div class="clearfix"></div>
         <hr class="hr-line">
         <label>Note</label>
         <textarea class="condition-notes" placeholder="Please describe wear or damage in detail." id="property[condition-note]" name="property[condition-note]"></textarea>
         <input class="customConditions" type="hidden" id="property[condition-list]" name="property[condition-list]" value="">
      </div>
      <div class="field small-12 medium-6 empty columns"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Tried with XPATH,CSS_SELECTOR, LINK_TEXT

[All available methods](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

Seems none of them working.

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/form/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/a[2]'))).click()
except:
    errorDuringFill = True
```

[image: Button on screenshot]

Using FIREFOX

Live purpose available on : https://www.tradesy.com/sell/

Category : Shoes ... & Accessories & Jewelry & Bracelets

Comment: What happens? Does it error out? What error message? Does it quit the session? Is the html code inside an iframe? Did you verify that selenium is seeing the same html that you are? Some sites are blocking selenium now, so verify that all the html is accessible to selenium.

Comment: @Stuart I'm able to fill entire form without problems. Only problem is this button here

Comment: there were many questions in my comment that you didn't answer.

Comment: @Stuart exception type `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException` . It's not inside iframe.

Comment: [search the error gave me this, does it help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48665001/can-not-click-on-a-element-elementclickinterceptedexception-in-splinter-selen)

Comment: Answer one solved it. You can post it as an answer. Thanks
I should learn to use google ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer taken from: [Can not click on a Element: ElementClickInterceptedException in Splinter / Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48665001/can-not-click-on-a-element-elementclickinterceptedexception-in-splinter-selen)

You can try the below 2 methods to click on element.

```py
element = driver.find_element_by_css('div[class*="loadingWhiteBox"]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)

element = driver.find_element_by_css('div[class*="loadingWhiteBox"]')
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element ).click(element ).perform()
```

hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the xpath to:

```
"//div[contains(@class,'condition-row')]//a[contains(.,'No')]"
```

You should really take some time and read on locators, instead of copying the full path from the inspector - it will make your job easier, and your day happier.

Comment: I agree, but for now this doesn't work `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'condition-row')]//a[contains(.,'No')]").click()`

Comment: what is the error your're getting ? always post at-least the exception class when you're seeking assistance, maybe the whole stacktrace if you're feeling lucky :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to link to the `condition-row` class above, just to exclude similar components of that page. And then we can use the class of `a` and `text()`

Try this:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(4)
e = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'condition-row')]//a[contains(@class,'condition-tags') and text()='No']")
e.click()
```