# How to wait for predefined element to be clickable in selenium script?

Tags: python, selenium

I've gone through many links and questions. So, I have a list of `div` tags that I want to go through and click and then do further clicks within it.

Thus, I already have the main divs inside a list which I am iterating though. The div I want to click is pre defined, so to say. `WebDriverWait` won't work for me here.

My script currently goes through most of them but ends up giving me the `ElementClickInterceptedException` for one of the list's elements.

Basically, I want to wait until the element is clickable before clicking it.

How can I do this? Any suggestions are appreciated...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can not click on a Element: ElementClickInterceptedException in Splinter / Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48665001/can-not-click-on-a-element-elementclickinterceptedexception-in-splinter-selen)