# ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted:

Tags: python, selenium

I have code like this

```
for i in range(int(total_fill)):
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,f'//*[@id="maincontentid"]/app-dashboard/app-itr-status/div[4]/div[{i+1}]/mat-card/div/div/div[4]/div[2]')))
    b = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="maincontentid"]/app-dashboard/app-itr-status/div[4]/div[{i+1}]/mat-card/div/div/div[4]/div[2]').click()
```

but i got this error :

```
ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <div _ngcontent-oyq-c49="" class="btnBox">...</div> is not clickable at point (753, 26). Other element would receive the click: <span _ngcontent-oyq-c4="" class="sessionTimeHeading">...</span>
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.114)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all try using `element_to_be_clickable` instead of `presence_of_element_located`.
If this still doesn't help you can use `JavaClick` instead of `driver.click()`.
So if this still will not work properly

```
for i in range(int(total_fill)):
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,f'//*[@id="maincontentid"]/app-dashboard/app-itr-status/div[4]/div[{i+1}]/mat-card/div/div/div[4]/div[2]')))
    b = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="maincontentid"]/app-dashboard/app-itr-status/div[4]/div[{i+1}]/mat-card/div/div/div[4]/div[2]').click()
```

try this:

```
for i in range(int(total_fill)):
    el = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,f'//*[@id="maincontentid"]/app-dashboard/app-itr-status/div[4]/div[{i+1}]/mat-card/div/div/div[4]/div[2]')))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", el)
```

I have to notice: it is strongly not recommended to use such a complex locators like `//*[@id="maincontentid"]/app-dashboard/app-itr-status/div[4]/div[{i+1}]/mat-card/div/div/div[4]/div[2]` they are extremely not reliably.
Also, please read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48665001/can-not-click-on-a-element-elementclickinterceptedexception-in-splinter-selen) about the `ElementClickInterceptedException`

Answer (score 0):

Usually this happens when the wanted element is covered partially or completely by another element(a an alert message or some floating element).

It says so in the error message also:  `Other element would receive the click: <span _ngcontent-oyq-c4="" class="sessionTimeHeading">...</span>`

So the first thing to do is make sure this element is either removed (by clicking the alert) or that the resolution of the screen is wide enough to be able to click the required element.