# Selecting an item from a dropdown list using selenium and request- python

Tags: python, forms, selenium, web-scraping, drop-down-menu

I am trying to fill a form up. here is the html for the drop down list

```
<div class="mb-3">
            <label for="cityId" class="form-label FormLabelsEn">City</label> <label for="cityId" class="form-label float-end">المدينة</label> <select class="form-select citySelect" aria-label="Default select example" id="cityId" required="required"><option value="" selected="" disabled="">اختر من القائمة</option><option value="Ahssa - الأحساء"> Ahssa - الأحساء</option><option value="Ar Rass - الرس"> Ar Rass - الرس</option><option value="Buraidah - بريدة"> Buraidah - بريدة</option><option value="Dammam - الدمام"> Dammam - الدمام</option><option value="Dhahran - الظهران"> Dhahran - الظهران</option><option value="Hafr Albatin - حفر الباطن"> Hafr Albatin - حفر الباطن</option><option value="Jubail - الجبيل"> Jubail - الجبيل</option><option value="KAUST - جامعة الملك عبدالله للعلوم والتقنية"> KAUST - جامعة الملك عبدالله للعلوم والتقنية</option><option value="Khobar - الخبر"> Khobar - الخبر</option><option value="Madina - المدينة المنورة"> Madina - المدينة المنورة</option><option value="Rabigh - رابغ"> Rabigh - رابغ</option><option value="Riyadh - الرياض"> Riyadh - الرياض</option><option value="Tabuk - تبوك"> Tabuk - تبوك</option><option value="Umluj - أملج"> Umluj - أملج</option><option value="Unaizah - عنيزة"> Unaizah - عنيزة</option></select>
        </div>
```

i am using the below code to click on Riyadh from the drop down list. But I am getting an error

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

dropdown = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/form/div[5]/select")))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(dropdown).perform()
wait
city = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/form/div[5]/select/option[5]")))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(city).click().perform()
```

I am getting the following error:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Message: move target out of bounds
```

Can someone please help me with how to click on the drop down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `select` class to select an element from drop-down. Like below,

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('cityId'))
# select by index
select.select_by_index(1)
```

**import**:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
```

Comment: I did the same and am getting this error 
raise NoSuchElementException("Could not locate element with visible text: %s" % text)

Comment: select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('cityId'))
# select by visible text
select.select_by_index(4)

this works, If you dont mind can you change the answer accordingly and I will select it as the answer. thanks a lot

Comment: oh one more thing. if you can help me with the check box.
i am using this code to click on it 
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/form/div[6]/input").click();


Im getting this error on the check box

raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (477, 1292)

Comment: `WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/form/div[6]/input"))).click()`

Comment: You can try other ways to fix this as well. Please refer the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48665001/can-not-click-on-a-element-elementclickinterceptedexception-in-splinter-selen